# Ways to do periodically data loading on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, etl

Consider the following scenario:

- A database with **lots** of data loadings every day;
- After the loading, no `INSERT`s are made, just `SELECT`s;
- The loadings are made from plain text files;
- While the loading is being done, I need the database to preserve its integrity;
- The data needs to be loaded on a 2nd server first, to be ratified (e.g. by the client);
- After the ratification, it would be good not to have to load everything again, just copy the data from the loaded server.

Today, we are loading the data on a 2nd server, and then **DETACH** the database and **ATTACH** it on the production servers, and this is terrible!

How can this scenario be achieved **without** DETACH and ATTACH the databases?

Comment: Questions: 
1) Does each days database get a new name or does it replace the previous days database?
2) Please give more detail of what you mean by "maintain it's integrity"
3) Does the ratified database have to reside on another server (if so why)?
4) How many concurrent processes are loading data at once? If more than 1, what is the concurrency level per db table?

Comment: Have you considered some form of database replication?

Comment: 1) No, same name, replacing the old database. 2) The users can check the old data or the new DAta, never something incomplete. 3) Is a server specially for ratify the data, so, is better to be separated. 4) Just 1 process load the data, a single SSIS package that loads lots of flat files into the DB.

Comment: Ozren, i saw that a snapshot replication could be a good idea right?

Answer (score 0):

A couple ideas:

- When 2nd database is ready, perform truncation on DB1 tables and bulk insert from DB2
- While adding a lot more complexity, staging tables